# Azure ServiceBusSessionReceiverAsyncClient - Mono instead of Flux

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a Spring Boot app, where I receive one single message from a Azure Service Bus queue session.

The code is:

```
@Autowired
ServiceBusSessionReceiverAsyncClient apiMessageQueueIntegrator;
.
.
.
Mono<ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient> receiverMono = apiMessageQueueIntegrator.acceptSession(sessionid);
        Disposable subscription = Flux.usingWhen(receiverMono,
                receiver -> receiver.receiveMessages(),
                receiver -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> receiver.close()))
                .subscribe(message -> {
                    // Process message.
                    logger.info(String.format("Message received from quque. Session id: %s. Contents: %s%n", message.getSessionId(),
                        message.getBody()));
                    receivedMessage.setReceivedMessage(message);
                    timeoutCheck.countDown();

                }, error -> {
                    logger.info("Queue error occurred: " + error);
                });
```

As I am receiving only one message from the session, I use a CountDownLatch(1) to dispose of the subscription when I have received the message.

The documentation of the library says that it is possible to use Mono.usingWhen instead of Flux.usingWhen if I only expect one message, but I cannot find any examples of this anywhere, and I have not been able to figure out how to rewrite this code to do this.

How would the pasted code look if I were to use Mono.usingWhen instead?

Comment: Yes, I got the answer (that you reposted below) on GitHub. Thanks for reposting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [conniey](https://github.com/conniey). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> By default `receiveMessages()` is a Flux because we imagine the messages from a session to be "infinitely long". In your case, you only want the first message in the stream, so we use the `next()` operator.

> The usage of the countdown latch is probably not the best approach. In the sample, we had one there so that the program didn't end before the messages were received. `.subscribe` is not a blocking call, it sets up the handlers and moves onto the next line of code.

```
Mono<ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient> receiverMono = sessionReceiver.acceptSession("greetings-id");
Mono<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> singleMessageMono = Mono.usingWhen(receiverMono,
    receiver -> {
        // Anything you wish to do with the receiver.
        // In this case we only want to take the first message, so we use the "next" operator. This returns a
        // Mono.
        return receiver.receiveMessages().next();
    },
    receiver -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> receiver.close()));

try {
    // Turns this into a blocking call. .block() waits indefinitely, so we have a timeout.
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = singleMessageMono.block(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    if (message != null) {
        // Process message.

    }
} catch (Exception error) {
    System.err.println("Error occurred: " + error);
}
```

You can refer to GitHub issue:[ServiceBusSessionReceiverAsyncClient - Mono instead of Flux](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/25717#issuecomment-982900350)